# Linux kernel parameter "net.ipv4.tcp_workaround_signed_windows"

Tags: linux, kernel, tcp

I am seeing some intermittent network issues when sending large amounts of data over a network and it has been suggested to me that setting this option to a 1 may possibly resolve the issue.

According to docs:

```
tcp_workaround_signed_windows  (Boolean; default: disabled; since Linux
   2.6.26)
          If enabled, assume that no receipt of  a  window-scaling  option
          means  that  the remote TCP is broken and treats the window as a
          signed quantity.  If disabled, assume that the remote TCP is not
          broken  even  if  we do not receive a window scaling option from
          it.
```

Can anyone who is knowledgeable about TCP clarify on this what exactly this parameter does? I am not sure what window-scaling is nor how "assuming no receipt of a window-scaling option means a remote TCP is broken" would significantly aid in such a situation.

I should also mention that I have not narrowed down exactly what the issue I am having is, just that intermittently this problem will crop up and data transmissions will hang unexpectedly (Wireshark shows a stoppage of packet transfer between the 2 machines) and that it has been brought to my attention by several others that setting this value anecdotally seemed to have helped.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest fixing this question so that it is about your problem. The community could probably be much more helpful than simply answering what this parameter does (which you could also probably look up in the documentation).

Comment: @user1794469 Thanks I think you have a good suggestion, but at the moment I am unsure and just wanted a bit more clarification on exactly the points that the documentation above told me - ie - window scaling, what it means to "assume" no receipt means the TCP is broken, and what it means to treat the window as a signed quantity.  If I narrow it down soon though, it may call for another question.

Comment: You can try to change the window size and see if that helps. I assume it stops sending packets because the peer doesn't send the ACKs.

Answer (score 2):

In TCP the window size is a 16 bit unsigned field indicating how many more bytes of data the receiver currently has memory to receive.

It turns out that 16 bits was not nearly enough since that would only allow 64KB of data to be in flight at any given time. This is why the window scaling option got introduced. With window scaling the field is still only 16 bits, but it doesn't have to count single bytes, instead it could count 2, 4, 8, ..., or 16384 bytes at a time.

The exact details of how window scaling works are not particular relevant to your question. Because the explanation you cite indicates that the `tcp_workaround_signed_windows` option only applies when window scaling is not used.

The reason the option only applies when window scaling is disabled probably is that it is a workaround for a bug only seen on systems so old that they don't support window scaling.

**The bug**

The cite mentions a buggy receiver treating the window size field as a signed value. This means that for all values up to 32KB it works correctly, but any value of 32KB or more will be incorrectly interpreted as a negative number.

The effect of this is that if you tell a peer with this bug that you currently have memory to receive 48KB more data, the peer will misinterpret this as -16KB and stop sending anymore data, since the next 1.4KB it wants to send clearly won't fit. (Or it might do something even more silly than that when it sees a negative value in a field that was always supposed to be positive.)

If you run into this bug what you will see is that when communicating with specific computers running some very old software, the data transfer will stall for no reason at all.

This can be worked around by never sending a window size larger than 32KB, which I what I would expect the setting to do from that description.

**What does the setting do?**

Reducing the usable window size from 64KB to 32KB will avoid connection stalls when communicating with a TCP implementation suffering from this bug.

It comes at a cost though. If transmission speed is limited by the window size, then reducing the window to half the size will also reduce the transmission speed by half. So transmissions which were already running slower than they should could end up going only at half the speed.

And this is why such a workaround isn't permanently enabled.

**Why only work around the problem when window scaling is not used?**

There is no direct connection between the bug and window scaling. So I am guessing the only reason window scaling is considered is because it is the best known heuristic to detect a specific buggy implementation.

And it does indeed sound likely that such a bug would get fixed before anybody started implementing window scaling. After all if you need larger windows it would be silly not to fix a bug limiting the window size to half of what it would be.

Comment: Does anybody know the model and operating system version of the buggy devices? Without any hint about these devices and their numbers, I found this option useless and silly: we don't know if our partners are these kind of bad guys... just wack-a-mole all !

Comment: @Massimo Those buggy TCP implementations were considered ancient when the option was [committed](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=15d99e02babae8bc20b836917ace07d93e318149) more than a decade ago. I suggest you assume they are long gone until proven otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But google-ing around, there are still "expert" suggestions "... if you have tcp/ip problems, let's try tcp_workaround_signed_windows*" ... and they aren't so old, sigh !

Comment: @Massimo From the description of the bug one can try to predict what the behavior would be if you were to trigger the bug. My guess of possible symptoms would be connections stalling or breaking as well as potentially corruption of the data being sent of the TCP connection. If you were to repeatedly see such symptoms with specific devices, I think it is worthwhile testing that setting. You shouldn't read much into that setting being suggested, only if you read confirmation that the setting helps in a reproducible manner on specific devices is it something worth paying attention to.

Answer (score 1):

[Window scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_window_scale_option) is an option that can be set in TCP that allows an extended size (greater than originally allowed) of the receive buffer. It is not obvious to me how this option would help. I guess maybe if there is a bug in the implementation that setting this one way or another might avoid the bug but really, TCP should work either way (in one case it may just be ACKing more frequently than it needs to).

Comment: Great, thanks! Care to elaborate also on what the implications of "assuming no receipt means the TCP is broken" and also "treating the window as a signed quantity".  Would the connection be reestablished if the option was set to 1 and no receipt was received? Is the window an unsigned quantity otherwise? What difference does that kind of stuff make and what does that even mean? The data coming through the window is signed/unsigned? Seems confusing to apply that characteristic to the window itself. Those are some of the more confusing aspects of this to me